# lattice histogram axis: how to fix lower limit at 0, but keep default upper limit?

Tags: r, histogram, lattice, axis-labels

I need to create automatically a lot of density histograms and I want the Y-axis to start at 0 and but without determining the upper limit, I want it to have the default value.
In other words, I want the result of axs = "i" for the lower limit and the result of axs = "r" for the upper limit.

I can't use ylim because I don't know which value is appropiate for each histogram.
I would like to keep working in lattice.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Example:

```
library(lattice)
histogram(rnorm(100,20,5), type = "density", scales= list( y=list(axs = "i")))
histogram(rnorm(100,20,5), type = "density", scales= list( y=list(axs = "r")))
```

Comment: the xlim or ylim? would `*lim = c(0, max(something))` work?

Comment: the default lattice color is obnoxious. Not that ggplot is anything better but still.

Comment: I thought about that, rawr, but the thing is I need max(density), but density isn't something that I already have, it is calculated by the histogram itself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is a feature I really like in Lattice

```
histogram(rnorm(100,20,5), type = "density", ylim=c(0,NA))
```

When setting the `ylim` or `xlim` just set the value you don't want to set to `NA` and R will figure it out

Comment: MrFlick, I can't believe it was that easy!!! I tried so many things and did a lot of search. Thank you so much for be willing to help people here. I'm sorry I'm new here and don't have enough reputation to give you a vote. Thanks!!!!